# Distance between two friends

Tags: mathematics, physics

Two friends are 200 meters apart in a concourse. They then both walk 100 meters each with their faces towards to each other. Yet after this 100 meter walk they are still 200 meters apart.

Comment: The question is a little vague.  For example, the two could be at an airport where there are conveyer belts, and the two could be walking against the direction of the conveyer belts such that they remain in the same location.  I'm not sure whether we are supposed to guess what is happening (situation tag needed?) or whether this has to do with some science since there is a physics tag.

Answer (score 2):

> One of them was walking backwards. Or they both were walking sideways in a circle.